# SharePoint Online views disappeared

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, view, sharepoint-views

Without an apparent reason tens or hundreds of views from a Sharepoint Online list seem to have disappeared out of thin air. All of the public views that are saved on the list are still there, but all "private" views created individually by users have disappeared. No changes were being made to the list or the Sharepoint site.

It now works fine to create new views but there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to retrieve the views that disappeared. As an admin, there also doesn't seem to be a way to see all the views created by users.

My questions are:

1. Why has this happened?
2. How can I retrieve the lost views?